# gRPC/C# - Unable to make request with stream response

Tags: c#, grpc

Here is my schema:

```
service Player {
    rpc GetAllPlayersOnMap(AllPlayersOnMapRequest) returns (stream WorldObjectData) {}
}
```

This is the code in my C# client:

```
private async void RequestAllOnlinePlayers()
{
    AllPlayersOnMapRequest request = new AllPlayersOnMapRequest();
    request.MapId = (uint)AuthorativeClientManager.Instance().GetActiveMapId();
    
    using (var call = gRPCManager.Instance.GetPlayerClient.GetAllPlayersOnMap(request))
    {
        while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            WorldObjectData worldObjectData = call.ResponseStream.Current;
            Console.WriteLine("Name " + worldObjectData.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives out error:

```
Method 'MoveNext' has 1 parameter(s) but is invoked with 0 argument(s)
```

This is the signature of 'MoveNext':

```
Task<bool> MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Any idea how can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Yes - as you can see, there's a cancellation token parameter, but you're calling it as just `await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext()` - you're not providing an argument for that parameter. The resolution is to provide an argument - you could always use the default cancellation token, e.g. `await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext(default)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate over the `ResponseStream`, you can use the `ReadAllAsync` function like so:

```cs
using (var call = gRPCManager.Instance.GetPlayerClient.GetAllPlayersOnMap(request))
{
    await foreach (var response in call.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name " + response.Name);
    }
}
```

This will iterate over the stream and get the `Current` into the response variable. In my opinion this is clearer, but if you want to stick with the `MoveNext`, Jon Skeet provides a solution in the comments.